# Drag and drop problems in Sharepoint

Tags: web-part, drag-and-drop

I really need help because I'm going crazy over here.

I want to drag and drop a web part on a web part page in the same web part zone.

**IE8**

In IE8 I can drag and drop web parts but the scroll-bar isn't working and I can't even scroll using `PgDn` button, so I can't move the web part down the page.

**IE11**

The scroll-bar is working but the web part zones don't appear when I hit edit so I can't move them.

**MOZILLA & CHROME**

Everything works fine except the drag and drop part, I can't move the web parts and from what I've searched on the internet I understand there is no support for drag and drop in Mozilla and Chrome.

Please, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: It would help to know what SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Have you tried to move it by simply editing the Zone Index value of the web part properties? It is 0 indexed so the first one in the zone is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered this issue with a custom masterpage. Ensure you're using:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

`IE=edge` causes all kinds of problems in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

in IE 11 Use compatibility mode when you are in the 'Edit' status for the page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these articles.  Basically there is reduced functionality in SP 2013 when using modern browsers such as the latest version of firefox or chrome.  Even IE 10 and 11 have limitations.

Here is a [list of features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#activex) not available on popular browsers.

Possible Other fixes/issues: [Uploading multiple files in a document library](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2010/12/uploading-multiple-files-in-document.html)